# How to estimate Hodrick Standard Errors in R

Tags: programming, time-series, garch

Does anyone know how to implement [Hodrick Standard errors](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/rhodrick/dividendyields.pdf) in R? I could not find any package for it in R. Is anyone aware of the same or any open source code that implements it? I want to use Hodrick Standard errors after the estimation of e-GARCH and DCC-GARCH models in R. I am not sure how to approach this?

The code to estimate Hodrick standard errors after a regression model I use is:

```
kernHAC(r, kernel = "Truncated", bw = 1,
  prewhite = FALSE, adjust = FALSE, sandwich = FALSE)
```

Where r is a regression object.

However, the sandwich package does not support GARCH estimator. How do I estimate Hodrick standard errors after a GARCH regression?